# Windows 11 X64-PRO Sound organization

Tags: audio, sound-card

I'm fighting with sound organization & routing inside my PC Computer running Windows 11 X64-Pro.

I have an external [MOTU-M2](https://motu.com/en-us/products/m-series/m2/) sound card, it connects to the computer via a USB-C, and to another USB port, I connect a headphone (HID). The goal I would like to get is to be able to record an instrument/voice via my DAW software (Reaper) and hear in live replay what I record.

I have a driver for the Motu sound card up to date. My PC is on its own card and micro/mixer under Windows 11. The headphone does not have a driver (HID).

(Sorry not able to add images ....)

Under Windows 11 I can indicate the Record and playback devices.

- For playback, I choose either Carte-PC or the ***headphone***.
- For recording the PC-soundCard or ***Motu***.
- In Win11 settings, Motu as Input.
- For the Output, the USB headphone.

In the recording software (DAW) Reaper, I cannot make the right choice.

- If I put (which is advised by Motu) the Asio option, I can only have
  the Motu in Input/Output. No more choice!
- If I choose WDM I only have the headset.
- By choosing DirectSound, I have both, the sound comes out of the
  headset but when I take the Motu as Input, I have only snoring!!!
- By choosing WaveOut nothing is recording!
- Finally, with Wasapi, it is not valid for the DAW!

Motu tells me that you have to see with Cockos (the company developing Reaper) and they themselves tell me that it is impossible to have 2 audio drivers under Windows 11? Do I need it?

I admit to being a little lost in all the choices.

On the other hand, I was told to see [Asio4all](https://www.asio4all.org/). I tested without success or incompetence.

Ditto with [Voicemeeter](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/), [Banana](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) and [Vb-Cable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/VirtualCables.htm)? !!?

Comment: Welcome to SE. If you have images that'd clarify your posting, just put them to imgur or similar and provide the links. Someone will add them to your post. You will be able to do it yourself once you collect some [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: I edited your question now for clarity and readability. Please check I didn't change your meaning, and that the links I put in are correct.

Comment: What exactly is "cockos"? What exactly are you asking if you need it?

Comment: @Ramhound Cocos is the company behind Reaper.

Comment: Apropos ASIO... you should use the ASIO Driver. It bypasses Windows Audio entirely, giving audio apps direct communication to the hardware, reducing latency. As a general rule it's a good idea to read the manuals to familiarize yourself with the equipment and software. For example; VB-cable isn't what you use for monitoring, it's what you use to route audio from one application to another; i.e. for example from browser or Spotify to Reaper for recording.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable input monitoring on Reaper. Right-clicking the Record-button gives you the options:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, there are multiple monitoring modes. You'll find detailed instructions and info on them from the [Reaper User Guide](https://dlz.reaper.fm/userguide/ReaperUserGuide674d.pdf) (direct PDF download).

A better, less latency-inducing option is direct hardware monitoring. How-to is in the Motu's [User Guide](https://cdn-data.motu.com/manuals/usb-c-audio/M_Series_User_Guide.pdf) (direct PDF download)